# JS - manipulate variables on Object.assign

Tags: javascript

How can I manipulate variables inside - `map.set(key, Object.assign({}, item));`.

Array for example -

```
const arr = [
        {
          name: "daniel",
          sum: "$100",
        },
        {
          name: "daniel",
          sum: "100",
        },
        {
          name: "daniel",
          sum: "$100",
        },
        {
          name: "daniel",
          sum: "100",
        },
      ];
```

desired output -

```
const arr = [
    {
      name: "daniel",
      sum: "100",
    },
    {
      name: "daniel",
      sum: "100",
    },
    {
      name: "daniel",
      sum: "100",
    },
    {
      name: "daniel",
      sum: "100",
    },
  ];
```

How can I split for the example inside the assign?

Comment: `const result = arr.map(obj => ({ ...obj, sum: obj.sum.replace("$", "")}))`

Comment: What is `map.set(key, …)`? What is `item`?